# How do I copy an inherited class properties to another class that inherits the same class?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0, inheritance

I have three classes:

1. Base
2. Primary
3. Secondary

Primary and Secondary inherit from Base. Base has several properties.

In one of the Primary methods, I will create a new Secondary class instance. Is there a way to copy the Base properties from Primary to Secondary w/o having to do it one by one?

If I do it one by one, it will be like:

Secondary.Property1 = Primary.Property1

Secondary.Property2 = Primary.Proprety2

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Which language are you using? This has to do with the language, not with ASP.NET.

Comment: I'm using vb.net, but c# works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). If it were my code I'd most likely simply map by hand, unless the sheer number of mappings made that unwieldy.